# how to add automate numbers in a loop

Tags: batch-file

I am looping in a folder that contain 4 files:

> ```
> image1
> image2
> image3
> image4
> ```

```
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    echo %%~nf
)
```

I want to add numbers next to the files from 1 till the loop finishes.

I want my output to be like that:

```
image11
image22
image33
image44
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLl3q.png)

```
echo get the name of the files
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
set count+=1
echo total= %count%
magick convert %%~nf.jpg -crop 2x2-40-20@ +repage +adjoin image-%%d.jpg
rem    echo %%~nf
              set /a count+=1
               echo %%~nf!count!
echo total= %count%
    )
pause
```

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? do you want the already available numbers to be copied, or are they independent? if the latter is true, how should the files be sorted for appending the numbers?

Comment: @aschipfl sequence number starts from 1 for example int+=1

Comment: Okay, but how to sort the files then? alphabetically, alphanumerically, or by creation/modification date/time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nancy your code misses the line setlocal... And if your path to the pics contains spaces better double quote them.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set count=0
:: get the name of the files
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
  set /A count+=1
  echo convert "%%~ff" to "%%~dpnf-!count!%%~xf"
  magick convert "%%~f.jpg" -crop 2x2-40-20@ +repage +adjoin "%%~dpnf-!count!%%~xf"
)
echo total= !count!
pause
```

Read about the for variable modifiers here `for /?` or [ss64.com/syntax-args](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
**Edit** /A was missing in `set /A count+=1`

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the result that you are after.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
            set /a count+=1
            echo %%~nf!count!
    )
    echo.
    echo Total = %count%
    echo.
    pause
```

Comment: I am getting null for the count = .. do you have any idea

Comment: Did you copied the whole script ?

Comment: Put the script inside the images folder or supply path to the dir command.

Comment: Create new batch file and past only my code into it, see if it gives you the desired result.

Comment: Since you didn't initialize the var count, that could also happen if the var is defined and contains -4 prior to executing the batch. @Nancy You put that code inside a code block (parentheses) so you need to use `echo Total = !count!` to have the delayed expansion working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please explain ?

Comment: The code works perfectly here, based on what OP wanted in the question he asked.

Comment: @LotPings can you post aas an example

Comment: @YanivK yes , but if add my code its not working , that's weird